# Quotes in variable - comparison and substitution

Tags: windows, batch-file, compare, substitution

I define variable like:

```
set LOGGING_MANAGER=-Djuli-logback.configurationFile=file:"%CATALINA_HOME%\conf\logback.xml"
```

Notice, that I wrap %CATALINA_HOME%\conf\logback.xml in double quotes, because path may contain spaces. And at execution step this variable will substitute to java program.

```
Example of substitution:
path_to_jre/java.exe %LOGGING_MANAGER%
```

Next code I can't change: (it's from catalina.bat file from Apache Tomcat)

```
if not "%LOGGING_MANAGER%" == "" ...
```

This if statement will fail, because variable contains quotes.

There I have one of 2 problems:

1. if statement fail (error occured).
2. without quotes when substitute to java program have problems (space is delimiter).

How can I change variable definition so that the path may contain spaces and if statement will work fine?

Comment: `if defined LOGGING_MANAGER` ?

Comment: I can't change that code :(

I want change variable defenition

Comment: @MCND forget to mention you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a [mcve] of how do you supply `%LOGGING_MANAGER%` to java _call_.

Comment: @JosefZ I add example. It's not all parametrs, but I think it's enough to understand the problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's unsolvable in the scope of the question

Comment: `set "LOGGING_MANAGER=-Djuli-logback.configurationFile=file:""%CATALINA_HOME%\conf\logback.xml"""` then `"%LOGGING_MANAGER%"` would be taken as one parameter without surrounding double quotes if supplied to a `c++` or `c#` console application (I don't have `java` installed). Note doubled inner `"` as `""` in above `set` command (uses `set "var=value"` syntax pattern). And `if not "%LOGGING_MANAGER%" == "" ...` should work as well.

Comment: Can you at least modify the `java.exe` invocation line?

Comment: @MCND it's just example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**note**: Not tested, but after reading the `catalina.bat` this is a way to deal with the problem.

If you are running this from a batch file, you can use

```dos
set LOGGING_MANAGER_FILE="%CATALINA_HOME%\conf\logback.xml"
set LOGGING_MANAGER=-Djuli-logback.configurationFile=file:%%LOGGING_MANAGER_FILE%%
set _RUNJAVA=CALL "%JRE_HOME%\bin\java.exe"

call catalina.bat
```

What it does is

- Save the file name with quotes in a separate variable
- Set the `LOGGING_MANAGER` variable using a escaped reference of the previous variable. As it will not be expanded, the final content of the `LOGGING_MANAGER` variable is `-Djuli-logback.configurationFile=file:%LOGGING_MANAGER_FILE%`

That way, when the `if "%LOGGING_MANAGER%"=="" ...` is executed, there will be not any problematic quote.

And now the `set _RUNJAVA` line. Inside `catalina.bat`, the contents of the `_RUNJAVA` are used to initialize the `_EXECJAVA` variable that will launch the server. `_RUNJAVA` is initialized in `setclasspath.bat` ***IF*** it has not been initialized by the user (code from `setclasspath.bat`).

```dos
rem Don't override _RUNJAVA if the user has set it previously
if not "%_RUNJAVA%" == "" goto gotRunJava
rem Set standard command for invoking Java.
rem Also note the quoting as JRE_HOME may contain spaces.
set _RUNJAVA="%JRE_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
```

The default value is `"%JRE_HOME%\bin\java.exe"`, we just add a `CALL` batch command before to force a second iteration of the batch parser that will expand the quoted `%LOGGING_MANAGER_FILE%` variable in the final command line.

Comment: thank you very much! I found EnableDelayedExpansion parameter, maybe it will help and it will be easy? I try it a little bit latter.

Answer (score 1):

```
for %%a in ("%CATALINA_HOME%\conf\logback.xml") do set "LOGGING_MANAGER=-Djuli-logback.configurationFile=file:%%~sa"
```

should set `logging_manager` appropriately so that you don't have to "quote the filename"

---

```
for %%a in ("%CATALINA_HOME%\conf") do net use o: "\\%userdomain%\sharenameforthedrivewherecatalina_homeisresident%%~pa"

set "LOGGING_MANAGER=-Djuli-logback.configurationFile=file:o:\conf\logback.xml"
```

may also work - if you know the share name for the drive where catalina_home is resident and assuming o: is an unused drive.

Comment: I think that two problems with this solution (nice one, good point) could be  : **a**) there are not short names (can be configured) **b**) the OS decides that some intermediate folder does not need a short name generated but it includes a special character.

Comment: @Magoo thanks for the answer, but it's not working :(  Behaves as if I will define variable as set LOGGING_MANAGER=...%CATALINA_HOME%\conf\logback.xml (without quotes)

Comment: @Magoo echo after your definition print -Djuli-logback.configurationFile=file:C:\x y z\Tomcat\tomcat\conf\logback.xml (without quotes or anything)

Comment: It would appear that your system has been set up to not generate shortnames (non-standard configuration). You would need to discuss this with your systems administrator.